# jQuery checkbox check all and remove all

Tags: jquery

Ok so i have this code that works great for checking and un-checking all of the checkboxes in a form. But if you check them all then check none of them then try to check all again nothing happens.

What can be done to fix this?

```
$('#yearall').click(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    $('.year:checkbox').prop('checked',c);
});
$('#yearNone').click(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    $('.year:checkbox, #yearall').removeProp('checked',c);
});
```

I have greated a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nf75M/

Comment: Does `removeProp()` take a second arg?

Comment: tymeJV it doesnt seem to give me a bit i will try to create a fiddle real quick

Comment: it would be good , if you can put code in jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: Working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/2169/ update your DOM in this fiddle if needed.

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nf75M/

Comment: @Unknown your fiddle doesnt work. After you click to add all check boxes and then click to remove them it doesnt work to select all again that is my issue it works the first time around not the second

Comment: don't use removeProp()

Comment: @Travis Working fine for me! which browser you are trying?

Comment: @Unknown I am using Chrome. and i just tested in FF and IE and your right it is working in those WHY Chrome Why!

Comment: @A.Wolff what should i use instead?

Comment: @Unknown, both fiddles work fine for me. Travis, it might be your browser...

Comment: @Travis use .prop('checked',false) http://jsfiddle.net/nf75M/3/  removeProp() is as far i can read in DOC usefull for removed element (IE9 memory leaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('#yearNone').click(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    $('.year:checkbox, #yearall').removeProp('checked',c);
});
```

to

```
$('#yearNone').click(function() {
    $('.year:checkbox, #yearall').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Once you remove the property, you can no longer set it in the `#yearAll` click handler.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nf75M/4/)