# cant delete all if checkbox all is check

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

my code is to checkall after I check the most upper part checkbox and then delete all checked checkboxes when I clink delete all button

my problem is I cant delete the checked boxes

I want to delete the checked rows

here is my **view page**

```
 jQuery(".checkall").on("click",function(){
                var checkall = jQuery(this);
                jQuery(".rows input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
                    var rows_this = jQuery(this);
                    var row_id = rows_this.attr("data-id");

                    var parent = rows_this.closest("tr");
                    var view_button = parent.find(".view");
                    var href = "personal_information.php?id=" +row_id;
                    var delete_button = parent.find(".delete");
                    var href1 = "delete.php?id=" +row_id;

                        if(checkall.is(":checked")){
                            rows_this.prop("checked",true);
                            view_button.removeClass("color");
                            view_button.attr("href",href);
                            delete_button.attr("href",href1);
                            delete_button.removeClass("gray");
                        }else{
                            rows_this.prop("checked",false);
                            view_button.addClass("color");
                            view_button.attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
                            delete_button.attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
                            delete_button.addClass("gray");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

and here is my **jQuery**

```
<table><form>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"></th>
        <th style="width:100px;"><center>Last Name</center></th>
        <th style="width:100px;"><center>First Name</center></th>
        <th style="width:auto;"><center>Email</center></th>
        <th style="width:100px;"><center>Birthday</center></th>
        <th style="width:auto;"><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr class='rows' id='".$row['id']."'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<center><input type='checkbox' data-id='".$row['id']."'></center>"; // data-id the id per row
        echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['bdate']."</td>";
        echo "<td><center>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text-decoration:none' class='btn delete gray'>DELETE</a> ";
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text-decoration:none' class='btn view color'>VIEW</a> ";
        echo "</td></center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="deleteall">
    </td></tr>
</form></table>
```

this is my **delete page php**

```
  <?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id =".$id;
mysql_query($sql);
Header("Location: user.php");
?>
```

Comment: Is it any error displaying ?

Comment: @dod29 nothing error displaying thats make it hard

Comment: @dod29 it just doesnt delete all the box that checked

Comment: do block you code by `if` statement i.e `if(isset($_GET))` in `delete.php` and `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: You need to send array of ids back to server to delete them but seems you have not done anything about it.

Comment: In FORM you did not mention the `acton` attribute . So your page will just reload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4689190/1059101 this could help you.

Comment: @YoYo how about the script? is it correct? i think there is missing i just cant pinpoint it

Comment: Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987583/how-to-remove-checked-checkbox-if-all-sub-check-boxes-are-unchecked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878918/jquery-checkbox-check-all-and-remove-all

Comment: Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987583/how-to-remove-checked-checkbox-if-all-sub-check-boxes-are-unchecked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878918/jquery-checkbox-check-all-and-remove-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `name` attribute to send data to backend:

```
echo "<center><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' data-id='".$row['id']."'></center>";
// and BTW `<center>` tag is removed in HTML5, so better to look for other way
```

and add a name attribute on `deleteall` button:

```
<input type="submit" name='deleteall' value="Delete" class="deleteall">
```

Now you can add some attributes on the form itself:

```
<form action='delete.php' method='get'>
```

and as you are sending array of checked values:

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteall'])){ // check if form is submitted using deleteall button
    $id = $_GET['id']; // get the array
    for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){ // loop through each ids in the array

        $id = $id[$i]; /// get the id in the iteration
        $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id=".$id; // make the query
        $result = mysqli_query($sql); // execute to delete

    }

    Header("Location: user.php"); // when all deleted then navigate

}
```

---

Well as per your comment you can use this with jQuery to send all the checked checkboxes back to server:

```
$('.deleteall').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // <---use this stop the form submission.

    var arr2send = $('.rows input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).data('id');
    }).get();

    var deleteallurl = 'delete.php?id='+JSON.stringify(arr2send);

    window.location.href = deleteallurl;

});
```

Yet you need a loop at the backend to iterate over all the ids in the array and delete them and after all the deletion you can navigate back to `user.php` page.

Comment: thank you sir but jquery is required to delete all the ID

Comment: So, you don't want to update your view, what is jQuery has to do in this scenario? Can you light more on it what exactly is required.

Comment: why it doesnt delete the IDs in the database?

Comment: @321X for now im studying the logic of jquery into php not to secure web

Comment: @321X that is not answering the question at any where near.

Comment: @Jai  yes i get it but i make it different but i learn a lot from your answer

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Injection Alert!!**

Even if your code isn't working:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id =".$id;
```

is a **BAD PRACTICE**!!

You're asking for SQL Injections and that is something you don't want! Even script kiddies can drop your database, etc.

Please check: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection, at least for your own sake as a developer!

---

Besides that:
Always put an `exit` after `Header("Location: ...)`

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php